# sending email from laravel using the mailgun can't set the FROM properly

Tags: laravel, mailgun

This is the way which I send the email:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

This is my mail configurations:

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    // 'from' => ['address' => '', 'name' => ''], //

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    'username' => env('****'),

    'password' => env('****'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => false,
];
```

This is my services configurations:

```
'mailgun' => [
            'domain' => '****',
            'secret' => '****',
        ],
```

When I get the email I see FROM is set to(None@mailgun.org). I would like to use different FROM based on different conditions, I don't want to hard code the FROM in the mail configurations. Please help.

Comment: any solutions from this? im having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem I can spot, seems to be that you have commented out `from` in your mail configurations

```
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

// 'from' => ['address' => '', 'name' => ''], //

'encryption' => 'tls',
```

This could be causing the problem with `->from` not correctly overriding, as it might be dependent on it.